# How to get confirmation of meeting sent in .ics attachment?

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am sending following event TO user1@example.com FROM user3@example.com:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//example.com//Appointment v1.0//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:abcdef123455
SEQUENCE:1
DTSTAMP:20160923T151743
DTSTART:20161101T211500
ATTENDEE;CN="user1";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:user1@example.com
ATTENDEE;CN="user2";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:user2@example.com
ORGANIZER;CN="user3":MAILTO:user3@example.com
LOCATION:Sweden
DESCRIPTION:Meeting
SUMMARY:Meeting
CLASS:CONFIDENTIAL
CATEGORIES:BUSINESS
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

When he opens it in Gmail he sees something like this and meeting appears in his google calendar:

[image]

Now when he clicks "Yes" ("Tak" on the screen) then I want to somehow get notification that he confirmed the meeting. But I get no email neither on user2@example.com not on user3@example.com...

---

I've tried with following:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//example.com//Appointment v1.0//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:absdfdsf78923
SEQUENCE:1
DTSTAMP:20160923T151743
DTSTART:20161024T150000
ATTENDEE;CN="user";RSVP=TRUE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION:MAILTO:user1@example.com
ATTENDEE;CN="organizer";RSVP=TRUE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:MAILTO:user2@example.com
ORGANIZER;CN="organizer":MAILTO:user2@example.com
LOCATION:Sweden
DESCRIPTION:Meeting
SUMMARY:Meeting
CLASS:CONFIDENTIAL
CATEGORIES:BUSINESS
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

But when I accept event on user1@example.com, still user2@example.com does not receive any confirmation email... Tried with different options of attendees:

- without organizer and 2 attendees
- with organizer and 1 attendee
- with organizer and 2 attendees
- with organizer and 2 attendees where one of them is organizer itself

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/reminders). In creating an event, you can use the [`attendees[].responseStatus`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#request-body) parameter to know the attendee's response status.

You can also check this [related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008667/sending-email-notifications-for-events-via-google-calendar-api). It is stated that the request needs to set the parameter `sendNotifications` as `true`.

Comment: I'v updated question - tried with PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION but still no confirmation email(s) are sent. As for sendNotifications keep in mind that I don't use google calendar api - I just send .ics file as attachment. And AFAIK there is no such option "send-notifications" or similar in .ics file spec.

Comment: Hi, @user606521. Did you find a solution to this problem eventually? I would much appreciate the feedback on this case. Thanks in advance.